# get values from contents of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, howler.js

I have this library [howler.min.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) and I'm using it to split an mp3 in 4 parts.
This is my code where I create the variable of the sound:

```
var sound = new Howl({
  urls: ['singasong.mp3'],

  sprite: { //function
    w0: [360, 290], //[begining,duration in milliseconds]
    w1: [650, 450],
    w2: [1110, 280],
    w3: [1270, 330],
    w4: [1600, 210]
  }
});
```

I want to get the second value inside the brackets (290,450,280,330,210) and obtain an array.
I've tryed with this two methods:

```
a = $.makeArray(sound.sprite.arguments); // One way to do it
a = sound.sprite.arguments.toArray();  // The other way
```

but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing to note: the value of the "sprite" property is **not** a function. It's an object with properties.

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted the comment in the wrong place

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate the keys of the `sprite` object, and push the array values at index `1`:

```
var values = [];
for (var key in sound.sprite) {
    values.push(sound.sprite[key][1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes. It should be noted (and this comment is probably enough) that there's no guarantee that the iteration over the property names will happen in any particular order. On most JavaScript runtimes, you'll *probably* get them in declaration order, but any subsequent activity on that object may cause that ordering to change.